# I have written a PHP language function that calls $translations from Mysql table, How do i capture the echo variable from my upload.php?

Tags: php

My upload.php looks like this....

```
<?php

$language = "DE"; //TYPO3
$user = 0; //TYPO3
$target_dir = "php/documents/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["rechnung"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1 ;
$documentFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

//überprufen ob die rechnung ist schon erfasst
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $check = file_exists($_FILES["rechnung"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false){
        echo lang("file was successfully uploaded"); //Der Beleg wurde erfolgreich erfasst
    }else{
        echo lang("sorry the file could not be uploaded"); //Entschuldigung, der Beleg wurde bereits erfasst
    }
}

?>
```

Mysql call function looks like this....

```
<?php

//Übersetzung funktion

$query = 'SELECT vAbbreviation, vDE FROM rLanguage';

$translations = array();
while loop ($row = $query){
    $translations['vAbbreviation'] = $row['vDE'];
}

echo $translations['error-download'];

?>
```

and Finally the table...

*Table name:nr_language

```
kLanguage(k-key) vAbbreviation(V-var)     vDE                vEN
      1          error-download       Entschuldigung....    Sorry.....
      2          upload               Der Beleg....         File was.....
```

I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function lang() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\documents\upload.php:18 Stack trace:#0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\documents\upload.php on line 18.....

How do i go about this?

Comment: From the snippet you've shown, you've not [defined the function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php).

Comment: You are calling the function `lang`, but you never declare it.

Comment: What is `lang` ? what is that supposed to do `while loop ($row = $query)` ? You didn't execute your query

Comment: Note : `if($check !== false)` can be simplified to `if ($check)` and can be simplified again to `if (file_exists($_FILES["rechnung"]["tmp_name"]))`

Comment: There's so many things wrong here. You're never executing the query, you're not fetching the row of results in the `while` loop, you have an extra word `loop` after `while`.

Comment: The assignment should be `$translations[$row['vAbbreviation']] = $row['vDE'];`. Your code is overwriting the same array element every time.

Comment: been trying unsuccessfully the last couple days to rewrite the function lang() that will enable me to call the error messages directly from the table. Preferably in German (vDE row). any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

1. So i created a sub-folder on my htdocs/php/ -documents(the sub folder).
2. In the sub folder i have four files:

   i. central.php
   ii. db.php
   iii. functions.php
   iv. index.php
3. I have then used require statements to insert content. I prefer the require statement over include because the former will stop script in case of an error hence more accurate.

My index.php now looks like this:

```
<?php 
  require("central.php");

  echo "<!DOCTYPE html>\n";
  echo "<html lang = 'DE'>\n"; 
  echo "<head>\n";
  echo "  <meta charset = 'UTF-8'>\n";
  echo "  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>\n";
  echo "  <title>document</title>\n";
  echo "</head>\n";
  echo "<body>\n";
  echo "  <form action='index.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>\n";
  echo "  <p>Bitte Mal Datei auswählen:</p>\n";
  echo "  <input type='file' name='document' id='document'>\n";
  echo "  <input type='submit' value='lang(upload)' name='submit'>\n";
  echo "  </form>\n";
  echo "</body>\n";
  echo "</html>\n";

  // Deklarationen
  $target_dir = "php/documents/uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES["document"]["name"]);
  $documentFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // Überprufen, ob das Hochladen erfolgreich war
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (file_exists($_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"])) {
      echo lang("success-download"); // Das Dokument wurde hochgeladen
    }
    else {
      echo lang("error-download"); // Das Dokument konnte nicht hochgeladen werden
    }
  }

?>
```

and my lang() function looks like this:

```
function lang($langAbbreviation) {
    // $varLanguage > TYPO3
    // $varUsername > TYPO3
    require ("db.php");
    $db = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nr_language WHERE cAbbreviation LIKE '$langAbbreviation'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($db) == 1) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($db)) {
        if ($varLanguage == "EN") {
          $info = $row->cEN;
        }  
        else {
          $info = $row->cDE;
        }
      }
    return $info;
    }
  }
```

on submit, i am now able to generate error statements from my database.